Fluentd sending wrong time to cloudwatch
In fluentd, a source is syslog and the target is fluent-plugin-cloudwatch-logs plugin. Everything works, only the time is wrong.
<source>
  @type syslog
  <transport tcp>
  </transport>
   <parse>
    message_format auto
    parser_type string
  </parse>
  tag isam
</source>


<match mysyslog>
@type copy
<store>
  @type cloudwatch_logs
  log_group_name /aws/mysyslog
  log_stream_name all
  auto_create_stream true
  region eu-west-1
  include_time_key true
  localtime true
  </store>
  <store>
    @type http
    http_method put
    <format>
     @type single_value
    </format>
    raise_on_error true
</store>
</match>

The timestamp in cloudwatch is correct 2 hours in the future, but the ingestion time is correct.
For example, if I put cloudwatch to local time:
ingestion time: 1719208787499 = June 24, 2024, 05:57:26 AM (UTC).  
timestamp: 1719215985000 = June 24, 2024, 07:57:25 AM
time extracted from message: 2024-06-24T07:59:45+00:00
time in message 2024-06-24T07:59:45+00:00


The only time, that seems correct is the ingestion time. How am I able to manipulate the time correctly, which would be 2 hours in the past?

Try setting the utc true in the source > parse section.
https://docs.fluentd.org/configuration/parse-section#time-parameters

Do you have the correct time and timezone set on the host from which you are sending logs?

It appears that Fluentd is adding a timestamp in UTC by default, which is then being interpreted as local time in CloudWatch, causing a discrepancy. To adjust this, you can manipulate the time to match your local timezone correctly.
Here’s how you can modify your Fluentd configuration to ensure the timestamps are accurate:

Use the time filter: You can use the time filter to reformat the timestamp and adjust it according to your local timezone.

Configure the localtime option properly: Make sure localtime is set correctly for your use case.


Here’s a revised version of your configuration:
<source>
  @type syslog
  <transport tcp>
  </transport>
  <parse>
    message_format auto
    parser_type string
  </parse>
  tag isam
</source>

<filter isam>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby
  <record>
    time ${Time.parse(record["time"]).getlocal("+02:00").strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%:z')}
  </record>
</filter>

<match isam>
  @type copy
  <store>
    @type cloudwatch_logs
    log_group_name /aws/mysyslog
    log_stream_name all
    auto_create_stream true
    region eu-west-1
    include_time_key true
    localtime true
  </store>
  <store>
    @type http
    http_method put
    <format>
      @type single_value
    </format>
    raise_on_error true
  </store>
</match>

Explanation

Source Section:

No changes are required here. The source remains as is to capture syslog data.


Filter Section:

The record_transformer filter is used with enable_ruby to transform the time record.
The time field is adjusted using Ruby code to convert the time to the desired timezone (+02:00 in this example).
strftime is used to format the time string properly.


Match Section:

The match section is similar to your original configuration, ensuring that the transformed time is sent to CloudWatch Logs.
localtime true ensures that Fluentd handles time as local time.



Adjust Timezone Offset
If your local timezone is different from +02:00, make sure to adjust the offset accordingly in the getlocal("+02:00") method.
This configuration should ensure that the timestamps sent to CloudWatch are correctly adjusted to your local timezone, avoiding the discrepancy you've observed.
